# Concise way to create single member list in Python?

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have some object `x` that may be a single instance of a data type (say `float`) or it may be a list of `float` types.

Is there any what I can ensure that `x` is wrapped as a list, perhaps being a singleton list if necessary, without checking its type or doing anything like that.

I'd like for something like `list(x)` to just always work, whether `x` was a singleton or not, but this doesn't work since a singleton isn't iterable.

Edit: see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26017248/567620) for some elaboration.

At the same time, I don't want to define my own function to construct lists from singeltons, and I don't want to do anything inline like this either:

```
from collections import Iterable
y = [x] if not isinstance(x, Iterable) else list(x)
```

If nothing more concise than this exists, that's OK. I am looking for some clean way of doing this that's already built into the language.

I'm sure some may think the `isinstance` approach is clean and good, but I'm specifically looking for something more concise that doesn't require me to write anything new before hand. I just can't find anything when searching doc pages and I'm not sure how to ask this question to a search engine.

Comment: When you find yourself trying to do something dirt simple that requires introspection or other esoterica, assume that you are defining your goal improperly, possibly bringing conceptual habits from another language. If you want a list of one or more floats, why didn't you just make one?

Comment: One problem with your code is that the string `"abc"` will be turned into the list `["a", "b", "c"]` – in most cases, this will not be the desired result.

Comment: @msw I appreciate the comment, but I also dislike it when people offer advice like "stop wanting to do what you want to do." Suffice it to say that existing system limitations on a large project that I cannot personally refactor dictate that what I'm trying to do makes sense.

Comment: @Sven that doesn't much matter because `list("abc")` already does that.

Comment: @EMS: I do like if people provide this kind of advice, since in my experience it solves 95 % of the questions asked on SO in a better way than the poster originally intended.

Comment: That's not been my experience on SO at all, but I will defer to you since you have more experience than I do. I am happy to read the advice: considering all advice makes me a better programmer. It doesn't happen to help my case right now though.

Comment: You said that this restriction is forced on you by the project you're working on. However, the restriction of "I don't want to define my own function" isn't forced on you, is it?

Comment: So this happens *exactly* once in one "weird spot" in a project with design flaws, and it can be solved with a total of under 80 characters of code, and you're surprised that the language doesn't have something built in to cover that situation?

Comment: I'm surprised it doesn't have something to construct singleton lists from singleton objects. That would be useful in a huge number of places where adding the cruft of an interface or managing user types is totally overkill.

Comment: It does have a way to create singleton lists from singleton objects. `[x]`. The real problem is that you want to accept two different kinds of input and silently convert them, which is something that is rarely done and hence has no language support.

Comment: @Antimony Accepting multiple kinds of inputs and silently dispatching different behavior based on the inputs is a super basic property of polymorphic code. It is included as a standard in many places in almost all object oriented languages. The real surprise in my question is that singletons are not considered iterable of order 0, because of idiosyncratic implementation details of things like `str`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an answer the question you didn't ask, but perhaps should have. I can only guess though because you failed to give the relevant context.

**How can I cope with an argument passed to me that violates my interface contract?**

You shouldn't try to. If I call `sum(2)` I properly get

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

because `sum` was expecting an iterable and I didn't give it one. If you are concerned that someone will call both

```
my_function(2.2)
my_function([2.2, 4.4])
```

The proper response is to raise a TypeError, not try to patch things up for the caller because as soon as you fix the first case, someone will then call

```
my_function([2.2, 'loretta'])
```

Do you cover that case also? What if they hand you a self-referential list? If you come from a strongly-typed language background, there is strong temptation to abuse Python so that it acts like Java. This only yields bad Python code: you've piled a hack on top of a defect.

And "type safety" is a bit of a canard too or else `double sqrt(float)` would not have to return domain errors, but it does. Should `sqrt` take the absolute value of its argument? Masking errors in call signatures only ensures that the defects go undiscovered, and then break later when you get an invalid argument that you didn't anticipate.

Comment: The "but I don't have time to do it right" excuse is usually taken by people who think they have the time to do it wrong over and over and over again. I appreciate the comment, but I dislike when people try to justify their weaknesses by blaming extrinsic factors. "No matter how hard you try" is another way of saying "I don't care to try harder"; good luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of anything like this that is built in. Your solution looks like the best bet to me, though you may want to use a sequence ABC instead of Iterable.

Comment: In my opinion, `Iterable` is exactly the right concept to check for.

Comment: The problem is I want something else that already does that checking, such as the `list` constructor. I'm surprised it's put on the programmer to do this check. I understand that the programmer should know when they are doing something with singletons, but it seems like just by default making a singleton list is a lot better than throwing a TypeError.

Comment: @EMS: I think throwing `TypeError` is a *lot* better.  Hiding errors is evil.  The attitude of always trying hard to make sense of expressions leads to atrocities like PHP and JavaScript.

Comment: @EMS: As long as `TypeError` is raised, it is, by definition.  That's exactly the point.  In PHP it's not an error to add a number to a string.  I strongly prefer Python's approach.

Comment: No, it's the only sensible thing to do. Having a programming language that tries to second guess you only leads to disaster and PHP. (But I repeat myself)

Comment: I guess what I am saying is that by definition, all singleton objects are iterable. Python may not wish to make them Iterable, but they are still actually iterable in reality. Yes, users have to know that a string is a list of chars, so therefore not a singleton, but things like this hardly seem like a good reason for keeping singletons from being instances of Iterable by default. Any singleton object anywhere is, by definition of iterability, an iterable object that can iterated exactly zero times.

Comment: If you want a single object to be iterable, put in a sequence of length 1. It's important to be consistent so you can reason about the behavior of your code and avoid bugs.

Comment: I can't guarantee that other people will pass me sequences of length one, though. But I'd still like *their* singletons to be iterable without having to check them.